# Having a case or if statement in where clause on Max Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

The issue is that I need to select the MAX date when:

If the Max Date from my_column is equal to today's date, I need to select the Max Date from yesterday.
If the Max Date from my_column is not equal to today's date, I can select the Max Date from today.

I am trying to do this using "case", but it is not working how I thought it would, sample code here is more like a sudo code to show the issue:

```
select account, name, street, due_date from my_table

where CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,due_date,102) AS DATETIME) IN (
-- if the date in the due_date column is not equal to today's date, I need to select today's -1 or yesterday's
case when MAX( CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,due_date,102) AS DATETIME) ) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE() ,23)
-- otherwise it can just get the max today's date from the due_date column
 then ( SELECT MAX( CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,due_date,102) AS DATETIME) -1 ) FROM my_table
 else  MAX( CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,due_date,102) AS DATETIME) ) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE() ,23)
)

)

and  account = '012345'
```

Comment: SAmple data and expected results will help us help you. That `WHERE` clause make no sense, and I'm not sure I follow your explanation.

Comment: Also [please don't use `VARCHAR` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) or [`datetime - integer` shorthand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations), and if all you're trying to do is remove time, [use `CONVERT(date, column_name)`](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime) not convert-to-string garbage.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, but any rooms for improvement or suggestions is gratefully appreciated:

```
SELECT account, name, street, due_date
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,due_date,102) AS DATETIME) = (

  case when CONVERT(VARCHAR,due_date,102)  =  CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE()  ,102)
   then (SELECT MAX( CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,due_date,102) AS DATETIME) -1  ) FROM my_table )
   else (SELECT MAX( CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,due_date,102) AS DATETIME) ) FROM my_table )
  end  

 )
 and account = '012345'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would *suggest* trying something like the following. It's not specified in your question but this assumes *due_date* is a `date` type:

```
select account, name, street, due_date 
from my_table t
where t.account='012345'
and due_date = DateAdd(
    day,
    case when Cast(GetDate() as date) 
      = (select Cast(Max(due_date) as date) from my_table) then -1 else 0
    end,
  Cast(GetDate() as date)
);
```